# Switch between horizontal and vertical layout using CSS (Flex or CSS Grid)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a table which looks by default as follows (up to 20 categories with up to 30 items for each category; each of the items will be represented by a card):

[image: Vertical Layout]

Now I'd like to give the user the option to switch to a **Horizontal Layout**, which should look as follows.

[image: Horizontal Layout]

I have started with a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stefanwalther/1uzh836j/15/

```css
.status-container {

}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col">
      Category 1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Category 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Category 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Item 1.1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Item 2.1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Item 3.1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Item 1.2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Item 2.2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Item 3.2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I am stuck, don't know which approach to chose (CSS-Grid, Flex-Box, ?).

Comment: CSS-Grid is the optimal solution since it makes spanning rows much simpler BUT I doubt if it could be managed without wrapping divs. The issue is spanning the undetermined number of rows required...if you don't know how many rows there are for each category you can't set a span number.

Comment: @Paulie_D I didn't get it to work with CSS-Grid - I think that flex works better here, as the accepted answer below shows. But thx for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure CSS `flex` solution is here. Supports any number of items per category.

See the snippet below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 400 100%/1.25 sans-serif;
}

#switch {
  display: none
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: .25em .5em;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

label:after {
  content: 'vertical mode';
}

#switch:checked+label:after {
  content: 'horizontal mode';
}

.category {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-left: 25%
}

.category > div {
  width: 25%;
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-width: 0 4px 4px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #248;
  text-align: center;
}

.category .header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #27c padding-box;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#switch:checked ~ section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

#switch:checked ~ section .category {
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}

#switch:checked ~ section .category > div {
  width: 100%
}

#switch:checked~section .category .header {
  position: static;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="switch"><label for="switch">Switch to </label>

<section>
  <div class="category">
    <div class="header">Category 1</div>
    <div>Item 1.1</div>
    <div>Item 1.2</div>
    <div>Item 1.3</div>
    <div>Item 1.4</div>
    <div>Item 1.5</div>
    <div>Item 1.6</div>
    <div>Item 1.7</div>
    <div>Item 1.8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="category">
    <div class="header">Category 2</div>
    <div>Item 2.1</div>
    <div>Item 2.2</div>
    <div>Item 2.3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="category">
    <div class="header">Category 3</div>
    <div>Item 3.1</div>
    <div>Item 3.2</div>
    <div>Item 3.3</div>
    <div>Item 3.4</div>
    <div>Item 3.5</div>
    <div>Item 3.6</div>
    <div>Item 3.7</div>
    <div>Item 3.8</div>
    <div>Item 3.9</div>
    <div>Item 3.10</div>
    <div>Item 3.11</div>
    <div>Item 3.12</div>
    <div>Item 3.13</div>
    <div>Item 3.14</div>
  </div>
  <div class="category">
    <div class="header">Category 4</div>
    <div>Item 4.1</div>
    <div>Item 4.2</div>
    <div>Item 4.3</div>
    <div>Item 4.4</div>
  </div>
</section>
```